# Extract CSV values from an array and display them Individually as a List

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I have an array of CSV values in my Database like category1[obj1,obj2,obj3..]

**View**

```
<?php echo $row_company->category1;?>
```

**Controller**

```
$row_company = $this->employers_model->get_company_details_by_slug($company_name);
```

The employers_model then calls a procedure which in turn executes the required query which displays the contents of row = category1 in this fashion,

**obj1,obj2,obj3...**

I want to be able to show this result without the commas and as a list like this

- obj1
- obj2
- obj3..

I'm Using CodeIgniter MVC Framework, I have some vague idea about the uses of implode function, and came across  preg_split too, But don't know where to start meddling around from, the view or the controller.
Any direction towards the solution would be appreciated.

**Edit : row_company in detail.**

```
$row_company = $this->employers_model->get_company_details_by_slug($company_name);      

    if(!$row_company){
        redirect(base_url(),'');
        exit;   
    }

    $company_website = ($row_company->company_website!='')?validate_company_url($row_company->company_website):'';
    $data['row_company']        = $row_company;
    $data['company_logo']       = $company_logo;
    $data['company_join']       = $company_join;
    $data['company_website']    = $company_website;
    $data['company_location']   = $company_location;
    $data['title']              = $row_company->company_name.' jobs in '.$row_company->city;
    $this->load->view('company_view',$data);
}
```

employers_model content

```
public function get_company_details_by_slug($slug) {
    $Q = $this->db->query('CALL get_company_by_slug("'.$slug.'")');
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->next_result();
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}
```

the procedure itself **get_company_details_by_slug**

```
BEGIN
SELECT emp.ID AS empID, emp.sts1, pc.ID, emp.country, emp.city, pc.company_name, pc.company_description, pc.company_location, pc.company_website, pc.no_of_employees, pc.established_in, pc.company_logo, pc.company_slug, pc.category1, pc.category2, pc.category3, pc.company_join
FROM `pp_employers` AS emp 
INNER JOIN pp_companies AS pc
WHERE pc.company_slug=slug  AND emp.sts1 ='active';END
```

Comment: Can you please show us how do you store the data ?

Comment: What are the contents of `$row_company`?

Comment: You can simply use `explode(',', $value)` which will split the value into an array of values.

Comment: @PratikSoni, data is stored by uploading a csv file into the db which contains the relevant data for that particular row.

Comment: $row_company is just a function to extract the values from the db using a procedure call from the model., 
it can contain all the values from that particular table @u_mulder

Comment: @Nigel Ren, Will look into it!

Comment: `$row_company` is a __variable__ And if you want some help you can show us it's contents.

Comment: @u_mulder, My bad. Its a variable!! I have edited the post showing its contents. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after referring many codeigniter/php forums.
Pretty simple actually,

```
<?php $array =  explode(',', $row_company->category1);
                    foreach ($array as $item) 
                    {
                        echo "<li>$item</li>"; 
                    }
?>
```

Thank you Nigel for pointing out to use explode function.

Cheers